# How to find out missing ALT attributes?

Tags: html, web

I am working with this following [site](http://kingsmarketinginc.com/) and I add ALT attributes in all images. But when I checked it in SEO Quack tool bars it shows 6 ALT attributes are empty or missing. So my ques. is that how can I filler those 6 images. any quick solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [w3c validtor](http://validator.w3.org/) should give you the line of the missing ALT attributes

Answer (score 0):

There are some regular expression for missing ALT attributes:

Please visit the link : http://www.rd2inc.com/blog/2005/07/regular-expression-for-missing-alt-attributes/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: Don't [parse html with regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)